# CSS/HTML5 Font color and size not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, colors, font-size

I am having great trouble getting a site to work with Internet Explorer -- big surprise, right?  The codes listed below work flawlessly with every browser that I have tested it on except for older versions of Internet Explorer.

p1 is the largest font, followed by p2, and p3 is the smallest.  Internet Explorer is currently reading p2 and p3 at the correct size, but p1 is smaller than both of them.  Also, p1 and p2 should be dark green and p3 light green, but all of text is showing up black.  I am using px instead of pt so I shouldn't be having this problem... any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
p1 {color:#0B610B; font-family: "Arial"; font-size: 24px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}     
p2 {color:#0B610B; font-family: "Arial"; font-size: 14px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}     
p3 {color:#659965; font-family: "Arial"; font-size: 14px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}
```

Comment: can you post the according html? seeing css code without seeing the according html doesnt help much in order to find a problem

Answer (score 2):

`p1` does not exist. I'm assuming this is a class? Try using `.p1`, `.p2`, etc :)

`p {` alone would select all paragraph tags `<p>`
`p1 {` selects nothing
`.p1 {` selects any element with `class="p1"`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using made-up elements? The CSS you posted will only apply to a p1, p2, p3 tag, e.g. `<p1>Some text</p1>`. But those elements do not exist. Older versions of IE won't style unknown elements. You should do one of these:

1. If they are headings, use the proper heading tags like `<h1>Some text</h1>`
2. Or use classes such as `<p class="p1">Some text</p>` and change the CSS selector to `.p1 {...}`
3. If you *really* want to use custom tags (a bad idea in general) then if you add them to the DOM with Javascript they can be styled in IE:

   ```
   <script>
   var elems = ['p1','p2','p3'];
   for (var i in elems)
       document.createElement(elems[i]);
   </script>
   ```